# How do I scan a QR code (which is a URL) without having to open it on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I want to retrieve the URL text from the QR Code rather than being forced to open it.

What should I do?

"Open Link" is the only option. There is no copy or view raw text.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'm on iOS 16.3 iPhone 14Pro, so I'm not sure if it works on your setup, but when I click small bar code on the bottom right I'm able to copy the link. Here's screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I assume this feature has been here since the start. Confirmed also works on iPhone SE2020 still on iOS 15.

Comment: I saw that icon but when I clicked on it, the URL opens directly. There is no context menu like in your screenshot.

Comment: You can also long press on the QR code itself.

Comment: I don't understand why, but when I view QR codes on my iPhone (iOS 16.6) it sometimes gives me the context menu, with choices about what to do, but for some QR codes it just goes directly to the link.  There doesn't seem to be anything I can do about it.

Answer (score 3):

The icon wasn't working for me either (iphone 13, 16.4.1) because I had switched my default browser to DuckDuckGo.  I switched the default back to Safari and the icon worked as it should.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Safari and Firefox have the menu; Firefox Focus, DuckDuckGo, Brave, Chrome, and Onion browser do not. This should be mandatory. Using iOS 17.2